# Как отсортировать массив по ближайшей предстоящей дате

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, momentjs

Подскажите, как можно отсортировать массив с объектами юзеров по ближайшей предстоящей дате (DD MMM). Чтобы в начале были юзеры, у которых предстоящая дата (DD MMM) самая близкая к текущей и далее на отдаление по дате (DD MMM). Год учитывать не надо. Только день и месяц.

[image: рендер юзеров по ближайшей предстоящей дате].

Сейчас у меня сортировка только по увеличение даты (DD MMM YYYY).

```
return Promise.all([birthdays, newcomers, newrole]).then(() => {
      return users.sort((a, b) => a.eventDate.valueOf() - b.eventDate.valueOf());
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: текущий рендер]

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то вам необходимо упорядочить список пользователей в порядке приближения **endDate** к текущей дате.

Я считаю, что учет текущей даты усложняет функцию компаратор, поэтому предлагаю решение в 2 этапа:

- Сортируем список по возрастанию дат без учета года;
- Перестраиваем список, сдвигая в конец списка те элементы, **endDate** которых уже наступил в этом году.

Вот пример реализации, правда без учета временных зон:

```
users.sort((u1, u2) => {
  const d1 = Number(u1.endDate.format('MMDD'));
  const d2 = Number(u2.endDate.format('MMDD'));
  
  if (d1 === d2) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return d1 > d2 ? 1 : -1;
  }
});
 
const now = Number(moment().format('MMDD'));
const firstSameOrAfter = users.findIndex(u => Number(u.endDate.format('MMDD')) >= now);

if (firstSameOrAfter >=0) {
  users = [
    ...users.slice(firstSameOrAfter),
    ...users.slice(0, firstSameOrAfter)
  ]
}
```